# Tribble dislike of Klingons and other aspects of their biology?

Tags: star-trek, biology

In the STOS episode, there is some evidence of tribbles not being completely simple "eating machines": They react to Klingons and in fact this is how Kirk discovers a surgically-modified Klingon agent.

Is the biology of tribbles further explored in other series or books? Given that Klingon are (I think) no longer simply "bad guys" do tribbles know this or do they continue to react?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not appear that tribbles have the capacity to tell whether somebody is a bad guy, but they evidently can tell whether somebody is a Klingon specifically. Tribbles are seen to dislike Worf (in "Trials and Tribble-ations", DS9 season 5 episode 6), but he is a good guy.
Tribbles are consistently presented as differentiating on the basis of species, as opposed to whether they are in the presence of somebody who is specifically hostile. The spy in the original series episode had nothing against tribbles personally, but even so, they didn't like him.

### What are they sensing and how?

The *Star Fleet Medical Reference Manual* (1977) claims that "the tribble has a keen sense of smell and is able to distinguish between various species and individuals by scent" ([excerpt](https://collectingtrek.ca/2023/02/15/medical-reference/)). The accompanying anatomical illustration shows nostrils on the dorsal side (C), connected by a nerve cluster (A) to the brain (F), all squeezed in around the large uterus (D). While this book originated as a fan work, a version of this image appeared in the background of two DS9 episodes and has therefore ascended in canon status.

[image: Anatomical diagram of a tribble]

Alternatively, in their original appearance ("The Trouble with Tribbles", original series, season 2 episode 15), McCoy confirms that a character is a Klingon spy by checking his heartbeat and body temperature. The tribble that screamed at him could have been reacting to the same physiological cues. I mention this because there are several other references to Klingons having a smell that's unpleasant for humans, or at least noticeable; the character in question was not detected in this way by any of the humans in the episode. So it could be that his scent was masked in some way that wasn't quite enough to fool a tribble, or else that the tribble was reacting to some other clue.

Either way, it seems like they have to pretty close to somebody in order to tell their species, as seen in the *Trials and Tribble-ations* novelization by Diane Carey (end of chapter 5 / beginning of chapter 6):

> [Worf's] voice trailed off as another sound bubbled between them. He frowned and shivered.
>
> "What was that sound?" he asked.
>
> "Soothing, isn't it?" Odo suggested. "The bartender called it a... a..."
>
> But Worf bolted to his feet as Odo raised the puff ball of fur he had been holding in his lap.
>
> Instantly the little animal's purring and cooing turned to squeals of alarm and it began quivering violently in Odo's hand.
>
> No doubt about the cause -
>
> Worf shoved to his feet, his chair flying out behind him.
>
> [...]
>
> Slowly and very unhappily, Worf took his seat once again, but did not shift toward the table. The tribble in Odo's hand stopped screaming, but did shudder and flinch repeatedly.

The tribble only panics once it is quite close to Worf, and can be soothed when he is present but not as close, though his smell should still be lingering. It doesn't seem that the tribbles react to Klingon aggression specifically - say, if there were some pheromone they give off when they're ready to fight - since the unmasked spy was calm throughout the process. It seems more like they are just noticing whether somebody is a Klingon or not.

### Why are they doing it?

We know from Worf's account (also in "Trials and Tribble-ations") that  there is a long history of tribble-Klingon conflict:

> WORF: They were once considered mortal enemies of the Klingon Empire.
>
> ODO: This? A mortal enemy of the Empire?
>
> WORF: They were an ecological menace, a plague to be wiped out.
>
> ODO: Wiped out? What are you saying?
>
> WORF: Hundreds of warriors were sent to track them down throughout the galaxy. An armada obliterated the Tribbles' homeworld. By the end of the twenty third century they had been eradicated.
>
> ([transcript](http://chakoteya.net/DS9/503.htm))

This evidently began before the events of "The Trouble with Tribbles", given the way that the Klingons in that episode react to the creatures.

It would be evolutionarily advantageous for a tribble to be able to detect Klingons, and scream. This would function as a warning to other tribbles, even if there is very little they can do to fight back. Many real-world animals react in a similar way to predators. Given the tribbles' very rapid reproductive cycle, it's not too hard to imagine them developing a sensitivity to nearby Klingons, on the basis that tribbles who were indifferent to their presence would be more easily wiped out.

A brief appearance in "The Bounty" (Picard, season 3 episode 6) confirms that there is at least one tribble in the early twenty-fifth century who seems to retain an antipathy to Klingons, though it is not clear whether this trait is innate or the result of genetic meddling. This "attack tribble" has several sharp-toothed mouths, and is also somehow able to notice Worf even through the wall of its tank; it's pretty different to baseline tribbles and perhaps just attacks anyone nearby. A short spinoff episode ("The Trouble with Edward", Short Treks season 2 episode 2) taking place before "The Trouble with Tribbles" shows at least one brood of tribbles also being subject to genetic manipulation in order to affect their reproductive rate and other traits; but Klingon-detection is not mentioned. These instances of genetic modification still do not tell us much about tribble physiology and there is no reason to believe that Klingon-detection was artificially introduced.

In the game *Star Trek Online* (2010), there are [a large number of tribble breeds](https://sto.fandom.com/wiki/Tribble), which come in different rarities and provide various buffs for the player. Many of these have no effect on Klingon, Gorn or Nausicaan characters. This appears to be for mixed reasons of lore-fidelity and game balance - players would expect tribbles to dislike Klingons, but also don't like being locked out of the most powerful items. The extension to other species is consistent with the Klingon history, and hints at some other instances of tribble conflict. The wide range of special tribbles is a bit silly (tribbles themselves are pretty silly too) but is broadly consistent with a fannish understanding that a rapidly reproducing species could have many different breeds, exhibiting different characteristics.

Comment: I remember reading that tribbles can smell if they're near a predator and Klingons set off that instinct.